# unexpected EOF while parsin

Tags: python-3.x

yo en esto soy nuevo asi que aportar mucho no puedo, he estado un buen rato investigando y por lo que veo este error normalmente da por la falta de algun parentesis pero reviso mi codigo y parece todo estar en orden[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberias poner el codigo en forma de texto en la pregunta para hacerlo mas legible. Donde termina tu función candi()?

Comment: no lo puse en texto por que no manejo bien la plataforma aun y no me permitia hacerlo, me decia que le falltaba algo y no supe que hacer asi que mejor tome captura.

Comment: pero ya resolvi el problema, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como no tengo la reputación suficiente para comentar, te lo escribo aquí.
Tu código esta incompleto. Después del ultimo `elif` tienes que poner tu código.
También te aconsejaría leer [PEP8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: si, despues de un rato de pruebas note eso, crei que al dejar la ultima condicion vacia simplemente no haria nada pero dejo todo el codigo infuncional